# Docker fails to build PostgreSQL 12 on Centos 8

Tags: postgresql, docker, centos8

Installing PostgreSQL 12 on Centos 8 fails with:

```
initdb: error: invalid locale settings; check LANG and LC_* environment variables
pg_ctl: directory "/postgres/pgdata" does not exist
psql: error: could not connect to server: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
pg_ctl: directory "/postgres/pgdata" does not exist
/tracks-bin/initPostgres.sh: line 12: /postgres/pgdata/postgresql.conf: No such file or directory
/tracks-bin/initPostgres.sh: line 13: /postgres/pgdata/pg_hba.conf: No such file or directory
pg_ctl: directory "/postgres/pgdata" does not exist
psql: error: could not connect to server: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
psql: error: could not connect to server: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding `glibc-langpack-en` solved the problem.  In the Dockerfile: `RUN yum install -y glibc-langpack-en`

I tried several other suggestions concerning adding different locale setting to commands such as:`initdb -E UTF8 --locale=en_US.utf8` or `RUN localedef -i en_US -f UTF-8 en_US.UTF-8`.  Those did not work for me.